# Simple 4-cycle permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I call a 4-cycle permutation simple if I can write it as $(i,i+1,i+2,i+3)$ so $(2,3,4,5)$ is a simple 4-cycle but $(1,3,4,5)$ is not. I want to write $(1,2,3,5)$ as a product of simple 4-cycles. So this is what I did:
$$
(1,2,3,5)=(1,2)(1,3)(1,5)
$$
but
$$\begin{align}
(1,3)&=(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)\\
(1,5)&=(4,5)(3,4)(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)
\end{align}$$
So now
$$(1,2,3,5)=(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)(4,5)(3,4)(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)$$
Can you please give me a hint on how I can express
$$(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)(4,5)(3,4)(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)$$
as a product of simple 4-cycles.

**Note:** We do permutation multiplication from left to right.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to write $(1,2,3,5) = (4,5)(1,2,3,4)(4,5)$ and try to write $(4,5)$ as a simple $4$-cycle instead of trying to do so for all the 2-cycles you came up with.

Comment: That is my main problem. I do not know how could I write $(4,5)$ as a product of simple 4-cycles.

Answer (score 4):

(2,3,4,5) is (1,2,3,5) conjugated by (1,2,3,4) so (1,2,3,5) = (1,2,3,4)(2,3,4,5)(1,2,3,4)<sup>−1</sup>.

While this may appear to be coincidence, I think you'll find it works quite well in general as suggested by Carl Brannen.

Comment: But $(1,2,3,4)^{-1}=(4,3,2,1)$ is no longer a simple 4-cycle.

Comment: @Vafa: By Carl's comment, $(4,3,2,1) = (1,2,3,4)^3$.

Comment: Thanks. I really hate myself. I am too dumb!

Comment: @Alex: One more question. How do you know that "(2,3,4,5) is (1,2,3,5) conjugated by (1,2,3,4)". When I look at this, it makes sense, but say you only have (1,2,3,5), how do you find out that "(2,3,4,5) is (1,2,3,5) conjugated by (1,2,3,4)".

Comment: Conjugating by a permutation is the same as applying that permutation inside each cycle, and then it is often easy to see how to get one permutation from another by conjugating.

Answer (score 3):

I'm strictly shooting from the hip (i.e. this is just instinct), but it might help if you consider the following:
(1) The 4th powers of 4-cycles are unity. I.e. $(1234)^4 = e$ where $e$ is the identity.
(2) This means that inverses exist. I.e. $(1234)^3 (1234)^1 = e$.
(3) And this gives a suggestion for a way of walking around the 4-cycles.

If you need another hint, come back and ask again tomorrow?